# Does having an action method that can INSERT to DB possess security risks in ASP.NET web server?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

In my ASP.NET web server, there is a action method that writes inputted parameters into the text file stored in the server. It's basically open to public, meaning anyone with a correct URL can write anything to this text file through the action method.

Today, the management told me to change this same action method to insert the parameter value in to the DB directly. I asked if I should add the authentication feature to it, but they said no, because they don't want to make changes to the legacy code that makes call to this action method.

Will this change possess security risks? If so, how can I prove there is a risk?

Haven't tried implementing this yet.

Comment: Who is intended to use this API?  Should it only be internal users or should it be anyone public who is trusted?

Regardless, there is a potential security risk since it could be used for nefarious purposes, but how important it is to mitigate the risk may not be something you can decide.

Comment: This is supposed to be used by computers that reports to this server occasionally, but it's open to anyone with a correct URL. Should I refuse to implement this for the security risk?

Comment: That is an opinion-based question.

Comment: `This is supposed to be used by computers that reports to this server occasionally` , If this is the case, you can maintain a list of whitelist IPs (in this case the computers reports to the server). And implement an actionfilter to check if request is comming from the IPs which is in the list of whitelist IPs, else drop the request with unauthorize. And if it is access by only local lan computers then you can check for local IP range.